# wxPython transparent gif not being transparent

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I'm trying to write code that displays my img2.gif with a transparent background, but if I try my code the background turns out grey (171, 171, 171).

I used this GIF Image

[image: img2.gif]

I tried python 3.9 and 3.11 and I am running Windows 11

This is my Code:

```
import wx
import wx.adv


class TransparentFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, id=wx.ID_ANY, title="Transparent Frame",
                         style=wx.NO_BORDER | wx.FRAME_SHAPED | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)

        self.SetTransparent(255)  # Set transparency level (0-255)

        # Step 1: Load the GIF image
        animation = wx.adv.Animation("img2.gif")

        # Step 2: Get the first frame of the animation
        first_frame = animation.GetFrame(0)

        # Step 3: Get the size of the first frame
        width, height = first_frame.GetWidth(), first_frame.GetHeight()

        # Step 4: Create an animated control for the GIF
        animation_ctrl = wx.adv.AnimationCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, animation)

        # Step 5: Start the animation
        animation_ctrl.Play()

        self.SetSize((width, height))  # Set the size of the frame based on the image

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = TransparentFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks in advance.